# When does the nuclear norm fail to minimize rank?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-rank, numerical-optimization, nuclear-norm

Given $F$ and $G$, I'm solving the following problem:

\begin{align}
\min_{t} & \quad \mbox{rank}(A) \\
\text{s.t.}& \quad A = \text{diag}(t) F - G \\
\end{align}

I used the nuclear norm, $\|A\|_*$, as a surrogate of the rank, and tried to solve the problem with ADMM. But in the cases when I know the ground truth matrix $\hat{A}$ with a small rank, ADMM outputs a matrix $A$ with $\|A\|_* < \|\hat{A}\|_*$ but $\mbox{rank}(A) \gg \mbox{rank}(\hat{A})$.

Is this a case that the nuclear norm heuristic doesn't work? What should we do when there is a matrix with a smaller nuclear norm but with a greater rank?

Comment: For readers who don't know the connection between the nuclear norm and SVD, take a look at : (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). For ADMM : (https://stanford.edu/~boyd/admm.html)